# Select rows with most frequent values of one column MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I'd like to select all rows from a table which contain 50 most frequent values of the column. I tried to use such a join, but it seems my choice of LEFT JOIN is wrong. The inner part of the statement seems fine. What should I change in my statement?

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl as t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE id > 123 
      AND id < 987654 
    GROUP BY col1 
    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC 
    LIMIT 50
) AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query?  Have you tried changing it to an `inner join` instead?

Comment: Inner join returns just 50 rows ofc. The weird thing is when I changed the limit inside the inner select to 5, the number of rows returned didn't change.

Comment: When using the `left join`, the results would be the same, some would just have a `null` id from `t2` (if you were displaying that).  Perhaps sample data and expected results would help...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a JOIN, have you tried using an IN operator as part of your WHERE clause?

For example...

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl as t1 
WHERE t1.id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE id > 123 
        AND id < 987654 
    GROUP BY col1 
    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC 
    LIMIT 50
)
```

Comment: For some reason I can't use LIMIT inside the IN clause

Answer (score 0):

Right join should work if your subquery is correct, returning any matching rows of t1 to t2 (as opposed to all rows of t1 and the matching t2's or nulls):

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl as t1 
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE id > 123 
      AND id < 987654 
    GROUP BY col1 
    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC 
    LIMIT 50
) AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize my query was OK, I just wanted to join on col1, not id :)

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl as t1 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT col1 
  FROM tbl 
  WHERE id > 123 
  AND id < 987654 
  GROUP BY col1 
  ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC 
  LIMIT 50
) AS t2 
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```